# How to configure R 4.3 to run on RHEL 8?

Tags: r, gcc, gnu-make, rcpp, rhel

While trying to install the Rcpp package in R on our RHEL 8 server, I get this series of errors/warnings:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'compilers'.  Stop.
Warning in system(paste(MAKE, p1(paste("-f", shQuote(makefiles))), "compilers"), :
  running command 'make -f 'Makevars' -f '/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf' -f '/usr/share/R/make/shlib.mk' compilers' had status 2
Error in if (nzchar(cxx)) { : argument is of length zero
```

After some experimenting, I realized other packages (haven, xml2) are throwing the same error when I try to install in R.

Based on extensive internet searches, my best guess is that my installed R version (4.3.2) is not happy with the version of gcc/g++ (8.5.0 20210514) that comes installed on RHEL. Or possibly with the version of make? (GNU Make 4.2.1)

Can anyone confirm my suspicions? (Or point me in another direction?)

If I need to run a newer version of compilation tools on RHEL, can anyone point me to guidance for how to configure RHEL to do that? Ideally, I am looking for a system-wide configuration solution so other R users on the RHEL server can compile packages on their own (ie, not requiring every user to have a custom ~/.R/Makevars). I'd prefer to configure R or the system so users don't have to mess with environment variables or other Linux-command-line-level settings.

Comment: Likely duplicate a few times over, please search for `[rcpp] devtoolset`.  Though g++ version 8 _should_ be good enough at least for `Rcpp` (if not for all packages these days).  So it maybe an issue with your R-on-RHEL setup.  Maybe ask the r-sig-fedora list?  You may have to / want to compile R locally to have a consistent view of what tools you have.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel! I'll keep searching, but I suspect this is more in the category of a problem with our R-on-RHEL setup. I no longer believe, like I did at first, that this is Rcpp's issue because the error is exactly the same with haven and xml2 and I'm sure I can find a pile of other packages if I tried 'em. We have another RHEL 8 server running R 4.2 and everything compiles fine with the system gcc 8.5 on that machine. So... we're thinking about just downgrading to R 4.2 on our new server as a possible solution.

Comment: Yes it is 100% *not* an `Rcpp` issue as it just as like essentially all R packages just calls into R for the equivalent of `R CMD INSTALL ...` and alike.   Now, there _are_ lots of people who manage on RHEL and alike.  I think it helps to have _newer_ rather than older releases and it clearly helps to have `devtoolset` as the defaults tend to be ancient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this by *upgrading* R on our RHEL 8 server from 4.3 to R 4.3.2. Apparently something with R 4.3 was breaking compiling packages on our server.